# Too much declaration and initialization in header file C++

Tags: c++, header-files

I've a big file of `Constants.h` file where about 200 variables(**mostly arrays**) are declared and initialised. I'm using namespace.

**METHOD 1:**

```
//Constants.h

#ifndef CONSTANTS_H_
#define CONSTANTS_H_

namespace LibConstants
{
    const int a = 12;
    const std::string theme[2]; = {"themeA", "themeB"};
    const int arr[2] = {1, 2};
    // and around 200 more declarations with initialization
}
#endif
```

This `.h` file is `#include` in almost every `.cpp` file but each time only very minimal variables are being used like `LibConstants::theme[0]`.

My ways works fine but doesn't **it allocate memory unnecessarily?**
**Shall I follow the approach**, to only define variables in `.h` file and initialize in `.cpp`?

**Like in below code:**
**METHOD 2:**

```
//Constants.h

#ifndef CONSTANTS_H_
#define CONSTANTS_H_

namespace LibConstants {

    std::string getMyTheme(int arg);
    std::string getMyThemeName(int arg);

    const int a;
    const std::string theme[2];
    const int arr[2];
    // and around 200 more declarations with initialisation
};
#endif
```

**Initialising in cpp file**

```
//Constants.cpp

#include LibConstants.h
using namespace LibConstants {
     std::string getMyTheme(int arg) {
         theme[2] = {"themeA", "themeB"};
         return theme[arg];
     }
     std::string getMyThemeName(int arg) {
         ...
     }
}
```

**Using it like**

```
//HelloWorld.cpp

#include Constants.h
int main() {
     //METHOD 1:
     std::string a = LibConstants::theme[0]; // arg=0 is dynamic and is being read from localStorage in my case. 
     //METHOD 2:
     std::string a = LibConstants::getMyTheme(0); //Here also arg=0 is dynamic.
     ...
}
```

Here, unnecessary allocation of memory for unneeded variables won't happen except for arrays which are declared as `const std::string st[2];` in the header file.

Here "arg=0" is run time involvement. Does it matter if some variable is not dependent on run-time but only compile time in which case it will simply replace the value of placeholder in corresponding `.cpp` file?

**Please correct me wherever I am wrong.**

Comment: Compile time constants goes to data segment in most implementations, whether you declare and initialize them in header or source files. For example say you have `int a[]={/*a big array*/}`. `a`  is not a constant but its initialized still has to go somewhere and the program still have to load it. So in this case I don't think it make a material difference. On the other hand, if a variable need runtime execution to be initialized, either by constructor or other means. It's better to wrap it in a function and create it on-demand.

Comment: @YanZhou Thanks for fast reply. So, you mean, both of the methods above are almost the same because they both are compile time and doesn't consume memory but only replaces their placeholders in each .cpp file?

Comment: No. Give a minute to compose an answer.

Comment: @YanZhou Actually, I am reading "arg" from the local storage and then getting the corresponding from Constant.h. So, yes, there is run time involvement.

Comment: Do you have access to constexpr from c++11?

Comment: @KennyOstrom I am almost new to C++ in these terms. Yes, I'm using c++ 11. So, I guess I must be having access to constexpr. But why is it so important? Yan also suggested same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `std::string` example. Consider,

```
namespace Constants {
const std::string str = "A not very short string";
}
```

`str` is a class type, it has a constructor, and it has to allocate memory to store its contents (unless short-string optimization is used in its implementation. Even in that case, it only applies to, well, "short string"). It is declared a namespace scope variable. So the program has to construct this variable at launch. Every program that has this variable declared, will need to allocate memory, and initialize its contents. That is an overhead you probably don't want, depending on how much that will effect your performance.

On the other hand, if you have,

```
const std::string &str()
{
     const static std::string s = "A not very short string";

     return s;
}
```

Now, you have a static local variable. It will be initialized at the first entry of the function. And it will be initialized only once. If `str` is never called, it will not be initialized at all.

However, note that the string literal `"A not very short string"` is still going to occupy some memory. Where and how it is store is implementation defined. Usually in the data segments, and the impact is usually minimal.

In contrast to class types. It is preferable to define fundamental types, especially integral types in the header.

For example,

```
namespace Constants {
constexpr int x = 10;
}
```

An optimizing compiler will most likely not to store the variable `x` and its contents `10` at all. Instead, wherever `x` is used, it will be replaced by `10`, and in some cases, coded into the instruction op-code (so called immediate operands). Of course, this is again an implementation detail. And such optimization cannot be relied on with all compilers. And if you take `x`'s address or otherwise ODR used, compiler will be compelled to make room for this variable anyway. But the bottomline is that, it will be very unlikely that you will be worse off by declaring this constants in header than defining it in an external source file.

Comment: Why is defining integral types for variable declaration preferable?

Comment: Please see if I understood correctly. Also, it would explain what I wrote in the last of my question. Yes, an optimizing compiler won't store variable x and value 10 because in this case, run-time involvement is not there. But in cases where run-time involvement is there like in my case where I'm getting the argument from logic calculation/local storage, it's good to get them through a function. Through function, I mean either your way const std::string &str() or mine Method 2. Am I correct? If, so then I guess following Method 2 is better since most variables in my file need run-time logic.

Comment: @user3241111 If you store the integral variable in a source file, it will not only require a little memory storage, but also preventing the compiler to do some optimization. For example, say the integral is later used as a loop count. If the compiler see it in the header, and see it is small, it might be able to effectively unroll the loop. But if you only declare it, but define it in source file, compiler won't be able to do it. To your second comment, the answer is yes. The key is to remember that global and namespace scope variables has to be initialized regardless if they are used later.

Comment: No, I won't be storing anything in the source file. Only the local variable instances in the function just like I shown in my Method2's cpp file, I'll be doing same. Thanks :) I would go with the Method 2.

Comment: @user3241111 If they are constants, there's no reason not to make them static.

Comment: You mean, "const int a = 12;" written in my header file must be effectively written as "static const constexpr int a = 12;" I thought writing static in namespace was deprecated. Anyways, can you please tell why is "constexpr" necessary to be added. And is it needed for declarations of those variables as well which I'm initializing and returning inside functions of that namespace?

Comment: @user3241111 I meant in your local variable. In namespace `constexpr` is enough. `static` would make it worse in some situations. Pre-C++11, `const int` is the only way. But after `C++11`, `constexpr int` is preferable. It enforce that its initializer is compile-time computable. And thus provides better compile time diagnostics if you used an initialized that cannot be evaluated at compile time without indent